# how to convert String to ArrayList in servlet while getting parameter

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

[image]

I'm retreiving the list of product bought by the user but I'm getting an error since in the constructer product is of type List. I didn't knew how to convert it

```
String buyer = request.getParameter("buyer");
List prodlist = request.getParameter("product");
Bill bill = new Bill(buyer, prodlist);
```

here is the code of the constructeur

```
    public Bill(String buyer, List<Product> product) {
        super();
        this.buyer = buyer;
        this.product= product;
    }
```

the attribute of the class Product

```
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private float price;
```

Comment: use generic list `List< Product> prodlist = request.getParameter("product");` @jan

Comment: If `getParameter` returns a `String`, you'll need to use a method that returns a `List<Product>`, or find a way to parse that `String` into a `List<Product>`.

Comment: @Deadpool same thing it is giving error  "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to List<Product>

Comment: look at the @JacobG. comment, use method that returns `List<Product>` object or by if string is `json` then by using `Objectmapper` convert it to `List<Product>`

Comment: can you show the `String str = request.getParameter("product");` output of this `str` @jan

Comment: What is `Product` and how did you expect some text (value of `product` query parameter) to magically become a `Product`, let alone a list of them? --- My *guess* would be that `product` is a repeating query parameter with the product *ID*, not the entire `Product` object. Re-think what you're doing.

Comment: @Deadpool the problem is with the creating of  the new object it can't admit the parameter prodlist as String cause I defined it as List in the Bill class

Comment: @Andreas the product has id, name and price as attribute

Comment: What is the *text value* of the `product` query parameter? How did you expect that text to become a `Product` object? --- How did you expect us to help you when you don't show what the `Product` class is, or what value the `product` parameter has?

Comment: @Andreas u can see the Product parameter

Comment: `request.getParameter("product");` what does this return, i know it returns string type but i'm asking for value @jan

Comment: @Deadpool depending on the case, here for example I gave in parameter keyboard and it returned it

Comment: @jan why you want to use list here. the request.getParametre() is giving you only single parametre 'String' right ?

Comment: @OnkarMusale yes it gives only one but Ihave many products in the bill

Comment: @Jan it's really unclear what you're asking. edit the question and give in detail description with your code, sample inputs, sample outputs.

Comment: @OnkarMusale in my application I have a user who selected many products in order to buy it.
I have to create him a bill which contains these products as well as their sum. I want to retreive all the product in the form of a list in sevlet

Answer (score 2):

*(Edited: using an object class.)*

Either

```
String[] products = request.getParameterValues("product");
List<Product> prodlist = new ArrayList<>();
for (String productName : products) {
    Product product = loadProduct(productName); // Or such
    prodlist.add(product);
}
```

or use

```
List<String> prodlist = Arrays.asList(request.getParameterValues("product"));
```

That [`getParameterValues`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues(java.lang.String)) is for multiple values for the same parameter `"product"` is possible. This is in general a `String[]`. The `getParameter(String)` method is for a parameter occurring only once; in fact a special case.

The same result would be for an URL `"http: ... my.html?product=pc&product=phone&product=tablet"`.

You should check that indeed the HTML contains several `<input name="product">`, maybe using the browser developer tools, generally evoked by F12 inside the browser.

Comment: thanks for answering but the list type should be product  not String

Comment: List<product> prodlist =  Arrays.asList(request.getParameterValues("product")); it needs a cast or parse

Comment: I have edited my answer; you need somewhere to retrieve a Product (from a database?).

Comment: for the moment the product are sotored into session variables. I just didn't understand the "loadProduct"

Comment: Having received product names from the request form, you need to take the Product with the same name from somewhere. Temporarily from the session you say, so get all possible products from there. You also try a drop-down list of products. In the web there are nice examples.

Comment: alright but this line  >>  Product product = loadProduct(productName); // Or such. is unclear for me :)

Comment: Sorry, that was my phantasy. "Or such" is the more realistic meaning. I do not know how to retrieve the Product corresponding with a product name.

Comment: please explain more

Comment: I think some sample from the internet will be more helpful and give more ideas that I can. Sorry.